# How to find the words on the left and right of the searched word

Tags: c#, string, text

How can I find left and right word in string from selected word string may contain, for example I have a string:

```
string input = "all our vidphone lines here are trapped. they recirculate the call to other offices within the building"; 

var word = new List<string> { "other", "they", "all" };

if (word.Any(input.Contains))  
{
    //and here I want find left and right word from found words 
}
```

So in desired result each found word must be attached as separate value, and should looks like this:

```
Found:   all 
Left:    (NONE)
Right:   our

Found:   they 
Left:    trapped.
Right:   recirculate

Found:   they 
Left:    to
Right:   offices
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example: https://ideone.com/hLry3u

```
string input = "all our vidphone lines here are trapped. they recirculate the call to other offices within the building";

var queryList = new List<string> { "other", "they", "all", "building" };

string[] stack = input.Split(' ').Select(s => s.Trim())
                                 .Where(s => s != string.Empty)
                                 .ToArray();

foreach (var word in queryList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.Length; i++)
    {
        if (word != stack[i]) continue;

        Console.WriteLine($"Found: {word}");
        Console.WriteLine(i > 0 ? $"Left: {stack[i-1]}" : "Left: (NONE)");
        Console.WriteLine(i < stack.Length - 1 ? $"Right: {stack[i+1]}" : "Right: (NONE)");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Alternatively you can use

```
string[] stack = Regex.Split(input, @"\s+");
```

instead of

```
string[] stack = input.Split(' ').Select(s => s.Trim())
                                 .Where(s => s != string.Empty)
                                 .ToArray();
```

Depends your liking of [RegEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hello, so I going to mark this answer as answer because it is implements and shows exactly asked output, but answer which is  below by @escepta gives same result, so both answers are good and useful, thanks for support

Comment: made a small edit also ... although it's not really needed in this example, you might want to check if there are empty entries and remove them (could be caused by having a double space between words)

Comment: yes it may be necessary, very useful solution in generally

Answer (score 1):

Split the `input` string

```
String[] haystack = input.Split(' ');
```

For each word in the query, do the search on haystack

```
foreach (var w in word) {
     for (int i = 0; i < haystack.Length; i++) {
         if (w == haystack[i]) {
             // print w
             // left is haystack[i-1] when i > 0, if i == 0 it's None
             // right is haystack[i+1] when i < haystack.length-1, if i == haystack.length-1 it's None
         }
     }
}
```